# Pandas read csv issue

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a really bad dataset that I want to read into Python to do some data analysis. Here is an example of the dataset:

```
             Column 0      Column 1
Row 0         (1,2)           [3 4]
```

Clearly, these values will be read as str values instead of numerical values. I tried to use ast.literal_eval, which seems to work with data values like (1,2) but not so well with [3 4]. I wanted my end results to be such that each cell in the dataset is a tuple. So the end results should be like:

dataset[0,0][0]=1

dataset[0,0][1]=2

dataset[0,1][0]=3

dataset[0,1][1]=4

What should I do in this case? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
match_pattern = r'\[.+\]'
extract_pattern = r'\d+'


def num_find(string):
    if re.match(match_pattern, string):
        str_list = re.findall(extract_pattern, string)
        return tuple(map(int, str_list))
    return eval(string)
```

```
data = [['Column 0', 'Column 1'],
        ['(1,2)', '[3 4]']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
```

```
    Column 0    Column 1
0   (1,2)       [3 4]
```

```
new_df = df.apply(lambda x:x.apply(num_find))
```

```
    Column 0    Column 1
0   (1, 2)      (3, 4)
```

Another alternative way, but not reliable:

```
def change(cell):
    cell = cell.replace(' ',',')
    cell = tuple(map(int,eval(cell)))
    return cell

new_df = df.apply(lambda row:row.apply(change))
```